# Pip-install issues

Tags: debian, pip, installation

I am using a beaglbone green with debian jessie and want to install som applications, e.g. python-magic, ansible etc..

When I use pip install or apt-get or easy-install the BBG doesn't fin any of the packages im trying to get. For instance pip install python-magic returns:

> root@beaglebone:~# pip install python-magic
>   Collecting python-magic
>     Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/python-magic/
>     Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/python-magic/
>     Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/python-magic/
>     Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/python-magic/
>     Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/python-magic/
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for python-magic

How can I resolve this? I can't seem to identify what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having network issues.

Can you access the web from the BeagleBone? Try

```
ping google.com
```

Comment: A bit late, but thank you for responding! The problem was that beaglebone uses ethernet over usb and needed config. I solved the problem by updating the namespace and gatway on my beaglebone.

Comment: Sorry, just started using stackoverflow. Dont have the rep to upvote ! :| sorry..